# change batch of sprite pyglet

Tags: python-3.x, pyglet

how to change the batch object of a sprite in pyglet?

```
def createSprite(obj, batch, layer):
    img = pyglet.resource.image(obj.path)
    img.width = obj.w
    img.height = obj.h
    return pyglet.sprite.Sprite(img, x=obj.x, y=obj.y, batch=batch, group=layer)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very ambiguous question... But, good theme.

In pyglet the `sprite` objects have a property called `batch` that can be changed in ejecution time. Is very simple, asuming that `x` is a object of the Sprite class, then:

```
x.batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
```